# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'product'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When I go to the url:http://127.0.0.1:8000/addToCart/1/ , it should add the product to the Cart. But it is showing >AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'product'

Maybe I've made a mistake.

models.py:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    session_key = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name='product_items')
```

views.py:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def addToCart(request, pk):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.user.is_authenticated: #user is authenticated
        mycart = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
        mycart.product.add(product) # <--- here is the problem
    else:
        print(request.session.session_key)

    return Response({'response':'ok'})
```

urls.py:
`path('addToCart/<str:pk>/', views.addToCart, name='addToCart'),`

What I need to change to add the product to the cart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`get_or_create(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) returns a 2-tuple, with as first item the `Cart` object, and as second a `bool` that determines if the object was created.

You thus should implement this with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

@api_view(['GET'])
def addToCart(request, pk):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
    if request.user.is_authenticated: #user is authenticated
        #     ↓ unpack the 2-tuple
        mycart, __ = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
        mycart.product.add(product)
    else:
        print(request.session.session_key)

    return Response({'response':'ok'})
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

---

> **Note**: [*Section 9* of the *HTTP protocol*](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.1)
> specifies that requests like GET and HEAD should *not* have side-effects, so you
> should not change entities with such requests. Normally POST, PUT, PATCH, and
> DELETE requests are used for this. In that case you make a small `<form>` that
> will trigger a POST request, or you use some AJAX calls.